# Как разрезать объект на несколько частей в юнити?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я ищу способ чтобы разрезать цельный объект на несколько частей с помощью кода в Unity, и до сих пор толком не могу понять что именно мне нужно сделать.

Много где говорят про Меши или ещё что-то, на этот счёт есть ассет (за 70$) в ассетсторе юнити, и много прочего.

Есть ли какой-то не самый сложный способ резать объект допустим пополам, использовав при этом только юнити и C#?

Я уже долго не могу найти конкретного ответа на свой вопрос, потому что в этом деле много подводных камней

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: Чтобы разрезать один объект на 2, наверное нужно создать 2 новых объекта имеющих суммарно форму и позицию как у основного объекта. А старый объект убрать со сцены.

Comment: Именно потому, что простого решения нет как раз и существует тот самый ассет за 70 долларов. Потому что там нужно учитывать и пересоздание развертки на двух новых обьектах. А в целом - все как написал aepot. Дешевле по деньгам будет купить ассет, чем тратить время на написание аналога.

Comment: Много де говорится про какой-то там "меш", но это лишь обёртка для какой-то  там "геоментрии" пересечения отрезков и прямых с выделением  выпуклых и вогнутых многогранников, которые в дальнейшем триангулируются. Херня по сути.

Answer (score 1):

Самым простым способом для вас, если конечно вы не эксперт в области начертательной геометрии и высшей математики, будет попросить знакомого 3D моделлера или же самому посмотреть видеоурок о том, как это сделать в том же blender, используя cell fracture. Режете, запекаете  анимацию, сохраняете и после импорта в Юнити при столкновении с объектом останется только лишь проиграть анимацию разрушения. Если же вы хотите запрограммировать разрез, посмотрите видеоуроки по тому, как разрезать двумерный меш плоскостью отсечения.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Есть бесплатное решение, нашел у одного прогера на просторах интернета.

Вот демонстрация его работы:
[видео в ютуб](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgoUmrhXyYE)

Описываю как сделать:

1. Скачать из его репозитория 2 cs файла:

   [Mesh_Maker](https://github.com/BLINDED-AM-ME/UnityAssets/blob/master/Assets/BLINDED_AM_ME%20package/Scripts/Mesh_Maker.cs)

   [MeshCut](https://github.com/BLINDED-AM-ME/UnityAssets/blob/master/Assets/BLINDED_AM_ME%20package/Scripts/MeshCut.cs)

И добавить их в свой проект в любую папку со своими скриптами.

2. Что бы реализовать разделение на части  - пользуемся статическим методом MeshCut.Cut (В скрипте, откуда вызываем - прописываем using BLINDED_AM_ME;).

Пример:

```
Vector3 anchorPoint = new Vector3(1, 2, 3);

Vector3 normalDirection = Vector3.right;

var pieces = MeshCut.Cut(gameObject, anchorPoint, normalDirection, capMaterial);
```

Mesh.Cut возвращает массив из двух гейм-обжектов - это левая сторона(id 0 в массиве) разрезанного объекта, ну и соотвественно правая(id 1);
Далее мы с этими объектами можем делать что хотим - накидывать ригидбади, крутить, вертеть, уничтожать, создавать клона фруто-ниндзи и т.д.

В сам метод Cut мы передаём:

1. gameObject - объект, который нужно резать
2. Vector3 anchorPoint - вектор направления секущей плоскости
3. Vector3 normalDirection - вектор, который указывает "вправо". - нам нужно указать, что бы код далее мог разделить объекты на право и лево, в зависимости от того, где это "право".
4. Материал, который будет применен к плоскости среза.

Возможно придется немного поэксперементироваь с векторами, но всё получится, код хорошо работает.